# How to change all values expect for the top values (by frequency) from a categorical variable in R

Tags: r, grouping, rename, categories

I have a data frame in R which looks similar to the one below, with the factor variable "Genre":

```
|Genre|Listening Time|
|Rock |1:05          |
|Pop  |3:10          |
|RnB  |4:12          |
|Rock |2:34          |
|Pop  |5:01          |
|RnB  |4:01          |
|Rock |1:34          |
|Pop  |2:04          |
```

I want leave the top 15 genres (by count) as they are  and only rename all other genres that are **not** among the top 15. Those should be renamed into the word "Other".

In other words - if for example the Genre "RnB" is not among the top 15 Genres, then it should be replaced by the word "Other".

The table I would like to get would look like this then:

```
|Genre|Listening Time|
|Rock |1:05          |
|Pop  |3:10          |
|Other|4:12          |
|Rock |2:34          |
|Pop  |5:01          |
|Other|4:01          |
|Rock |1:34          |
|Pop  |2:04          |
```

How would I approach this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to look into `tidyverse` you may do something like this. I have tried to mimic your data frame but added some more rows.

You start with data > group_by Genre > order > chose top 5

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)
Data <- data.frame(
  listen = format(as.POSIXlt(paste0(
      as.character(sample(1:5)),
      ':',
      as.character(sample(0:59))), format = '%H:%M'),format = '%H:%M'),
  Genre = sample(c("Rock", "Pop", 'RnB'), 120, replace = TRUE)
)


Data %>%
  group_by(Genre ) %>%
  arrange(desc(listen)) %>% 
  select(listen) %>% 
  top_n(5) %>% 
  arrange(Genre)
#> Adding missing grouping variables: `Genre`
#> Selecting by listen
#> # A tibble: 15 x 2
#> # Groups:   Genre [3]
#>    Genre listen
#>    <chr> <chr> 
#>  1 Pop   05:47 
#>  2 Pop   05:47 
#>  3 Pop   05:43 
#>  4 Pop   05:41 
#>  5 Pop   05:28 
#>  6 RnB   05:54 
#>  7 RnB   05:44 
#>  8 RnB   05:43 
#>  9 RnB   05:29 
#> 10 RnB   05:28 
#> 11 Rock  05:54 
#> 12 Rock  05:44 
#> 13 Rock  05:41 
#> 14 Rock  05:29 
#> 15 Rock  05:26
```

---

Sorry, if I have misunderstood what you wanted. If you assign the code to a new data.frame and make an anti_join to the original DF and then mutate Genre to *others* it should be what you want - I guess.

```
df <- Data %>%
  group_by(Genre ) %>%
  arrange(desc(listen)) %>% 
  select(listen) %>% 
  top_n(5) %>% 
  arrange(Genre) 

# make an anti_join and assign 'other' to Genre

anti_join(Data, df) %>% 
  mutate(Genre = 'others')
```

---

*Next Edit*

Hopefully I have now understood your question. You want just to count how often the Genres occure in your data and give those which do not belong to the top 15 the name *Others*. Maybe I was mislead by the data frame you offered which shows only 3 Genres. So I looked up in *Wikipedia* and added a few, invented some own Genres and used LETTERS to build up a DF with sufficient numbers of Genre.

With `count(Genre)` the occurences of Genres are counted, and then arranged in descending order. I have then introduced a new column with the row numbers. You can delete this if you want, as it is only there to do the next step which is introducing another column - I have chosen to make a new column, instead of renaming all the names in *Genre* - with the name *Top15* an giving every Genre which is on place(in row) 16 or later the name *Others* and keeping the rest unchanged.

`head(20)` just prints the first 20 rows of this DF.

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)
Data <- data.frame(
  listen = format(as.POSIXlt(paste0(
      as.character(sample(1:5)),
      ':',
      as.character(sample(0:59))), format = '%H:%M'),format = '%H:%M'),
  Genre = sample(c("Rock", "Pop", 'RnB', 'Opera',
                   'Birthday Songs', 'HipHop',
                   'Chinese Songs', 'Napoli Lovesongs',
                   'Benga', 'Bongo', 'Kawito', 'Noise',
                   'County Blues','Mambo', 'Reggae',
                   LETTERS[0:24]), 300, replace = TRUE)
)

Data %>% count(Genre) %>% 
  arrange(desc(n)) %>% 
  mutate(place = row_number()) %>% 
  mutate(Top15 = ifelse(place > 15, 'Others', Genre)) %>% 
  head(20)
#> # A tibble: 20 x 4
#>    Genre            n place Top15       
#>    <chr>        <int> <int> <chr>       
#>  1 N               15     1 N           
#>  2 T               13     2 T           
#>  3 V               13     3 V           
#>  4 K               12     4 K           
#>  5 Rock            11     5 Rock        
#>  6 X               11     6 X           
#>  7 E               10     7 E           
#>  8 W               10     8 W           
#>  9 Benga            9     9 Benga       
#> 10 County Blues     9    10 County Blues
#> 11 G                9    11 G           
#> 12 J                9    12 J           
#> 13 M                9    13 M           
#> 14 Reggae           9    14 Reggae      
#> 15 B                8    15 B           
#> 16 D                8    16 Others      
#> 17 I                8    17 Others      
#> 18 P                8    18 Others      
#> 19 R                8    19 Others      
#> 20 S                8    20 Others
```

I hope this was what you were looking for

Comment: Hey @MarBlo, thank you! As I understand it, the code above selects only the values that are among the top 5. However, is there a way to say that all other values should be renamed "Other"?

Comment: I also update my answer. Changes after the horizontal line.

Comment: Hey @MarBlo, as I understand it, your function arranges the table by "listening time"  - so longest listening time on top, lowest on the bottom. However, what I am looking for is an arrangement by Count/Frequency, meaning that I want to have the top 15 genres by count/their number of occurence in the data (and rename all others).

Comment: @lole_emily Next update / edit to my post is made.  I hope this is now what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `df` with your `data.frame` to check if you get the desired output :

```
df <- data.frame(Genre=sample(letters, 1000, replace=TRUE),
                 ListeningTime=runif(1000, 3, 5))
```

> ```
> > head(df)
>   Genre ListeningTime
> 1     j      3.437013
> 2     n      4.151121
> 3     p      3.109044
> 4     z      4.529619
> 5     h      4.043982
> 6     i      3.590463
> ```

```
freq <- table(df$Genre)
sorted <- sort(freq, decreasing=TRUE)  # Sorted by frequency of df$Genre
```

> ```
> > sorted
>  d  x  o  q  r  u  g  i  j  f  a  p  b  e  v  n  w  c  k  m  z  l  h  t  y  s 
> 53 50 46 45 45 42 41 41 40 39 38 38 37 37 37 36 36 35 35 35 35 34 33 33 30 29
> ```

```
not_top_15 <- names(sorted[-1*1:15])  # The Genres not in the top 15
pos <- which(df$Genre %in% not_top_15)  # Their position in df
```

> ```
> > head(df[pos, ])  # The original data, without the top 15 Genres
>    Genre ListeningTime
> 2      n      4.151121
> 4      z      4.529619
> 5      h      4.043982
> 7      s      3.521054
> 16     w      3.528091
> 18     h      4.588815
> ```

Comment: Hi @Trusky! Thanks for your quick reply! The output I am looking for is the same table as in my example above. The difference I am looking for i that I want Genres that are listened to very infrequently (not among the 15 most listened Genres) to be grouped into "Other".

Comment: I just updated the output printed on the answer, try it out. I think it does what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)
compute_listen_time <- function(n.songs) {
  min <- sample(1:15, n.songs, replace = TRUE)
  sec <- sample(0:59, n.songs, replace = TRUE)
  sec <- ifelse(sec > 10, sec, paste0("0", sec))
  paste0(min, ":", sec)
}



df <- data.frame(
  Genre = sample(c("Rock", "Pop", "RnB", "Rock", "Pop"), 100, replace = TRUE),
  Listen_Time = compute_listen_time(100)
)


df <- add_count(df, Genre, name = "count") %>%
  mutate(
    rank = dense_rank(desc(count)),
    group = ifelse(rank <= 15, Genre, "other")
  )
df
```

Comment: Hey @Eyayaw! Thanks! Unfortunately, this function assumes that the last 15 values in the data frame are the ones with the highest count. What I got after trying the function was a table with only one genre and all others renamed to "other", since my dataset is quite large.

Comment: I updated my answer. How many genres of songs you have in the data?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a data.table solution. Let's assume your data.frame is called `music`, then:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(music)

other_genres <- music[, .N, by = genre][order(-N)][16:.N, genre]

music[genre %chin% other_genres, genre := "other"]
```

The first line of effective code counts the appearances by genre, sorts it from largest to smallest and selects from the 16 down to the last one, assigning the result to a variable called `other_genres`.
The second line will check which genres are in that list, and update their name to `"other"`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty neat solution with the `forcats` package applied here to the `diamonds` dataset to only name the top 5 `clarity` values and bundle the rest as "Other"

```r
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

diamonds %>%
  mutate(clarity2 = fct_lump(fct_infreq(clarity), n = 5))
```

Result:

```r
# A tibble: 53,940 x 11
   carat cut       color clarity depth table price     x     y     z clarity2
   <dbl> <ord>     <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <ord>   
 1 0.23  Ideal     E     SI2      61.5    55   326  3.95  3.98  2.43 SI2     
 2 0.21  Premium   E     SI1      59.8    61   326  3.89  3.84  2.31 SI1     
 3 0.23  Good      E     VS1      56.9    65   327  4.05  4.07  2.31 VS1     
 4 0.290 Premium   I     VS2      62.4    58   334  4.2   4.23  2.63 VS2     
 5 0.31  Good      J     SI2      63.3    58   335  4.34  4.35  2.75 SI2     
 6 0.24  Very Good J     VVS2     62.8    57   336  3.94  3.96  2.48 VVS2    
 7 0.24  Very Good I     VVS1     62.3    57   336  3.95  3.98  2.47 Other   
 8 0.26  Very Good H     SI1      61.9    55   337  4.07  4.11  2.53 SI1     
 9 0.22  Fair      E     VS2      65.1    61   337  3.87  3.78  2.49 VS2     
10 0.23  Very Good H     VS1      59.4    61   338  4     4.05  2.39 VS1     
# … with 53,930 more rows
```